# TypeForwardedTo, explicitly implemented interfaces and events

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to refactor a code base.  This requires moving types to different assemblies to fix some dependency issues.  I want to avoid requiring my customers to recompile as a result of these changes.  I've noticed that interfaces that are explicitly implemented and declare events do not forward correctly.  For example:

Foo.dll defines:

```
public interface IFooInterface
{
    void Foo();

    event EventHandler FooEvent;
}
```

My customer's FooProgram.exe depends on Foo.dll and defines:

```
public class Foo : IFooInterface
{
    event EventHandler IFooInterface.FooEvent
    {
        add { }

        remove { }
    }

    void IFooInterface.Foo() { }
}
```

Now I move the type.  I create a new assembly NewFoo.dll.  I move IFooInterface from the old assembly to the new assembly and put it under the same namespace.  Foo.csproj takes a project reference to NewFoo.csproj and I add the forwarding attribute:

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(IFooInterface))]
```

I place Foo.dll and NewFoo.dll in the bin directory for Foo.exe and Foo.exe errors with:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'add_FooEvent' in type 'FooProgram.Foo' from assembly 'FooProgram, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
       at FooProgram.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Why does this happen?  If I implicitly implement the interface on Foo it works, but that doesn't do me any good as it means anyone who wrote vb.net code against my library will break.  What other constructs have this problem with Type Fowrarding?  Is there a way to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in the old version of .NET Framework we're using (4.5).  I upgraded to 4.8 and it works as expected.  I found [this blog post by Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/nov/23/net-standard-20-making-sense-of-net-again) that describes how TypeForwardTo is what makes .NET Standard capable of resolving to the correct targets.  This made me realize it must work for all types on a more modern version of the framework.